# Is this a specific pattern and what is its purpose?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, use-case

I recently stumbled over the following C++ Code which confused me a bit:

```
class One {/*definition*/};
template<class Base > class Two : public Base {/*definition*/};
template<class Base > class Three : public Base {/*definition*/};
template<class Base > class Four : public Base {/*definition*/};
class Five : public Four < Three< Two < One > > > {/*definition*/};
```

I know the purpose of templates and more or less when and how to use them.

Is there a name or a common pattern for a cascade of several templates?

When would I use this pattern (instead of anything less complex)?

P.S.: definition of class Five actually is empty.

Comment: seems like a poor man's multiple inheritance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying the partern of a particular block of code.

Comment: A form of CRTP, I believe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @glampert, this isn't CRTP, there is no template reference to any specific class, i.e., class Three : Two<Three> {}; would be CRTP.  I think it is a mixin (which in C++ is a hybrid of inheritance and templating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess I'd say that the author was implementing a form of mixin.

The class with the object's primary functionality would be `One`, but `Two`, `Three` etc are adding various pieces of orthogonal functionality that aren't particularly coupled to the primary class. `Five` is then just a placeholder for taking the aggregation.

Comment: From this context it makes quite a lot of sense.